# Text hide while use top fixed nav

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using `top navigation fixed` then my div text is hiding behind top navigation how to fix it?

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <style>
  *{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
  .myNav{ width:100%; background:#ccc; position:fixed; top:0px;}
  .myNav li{ list-style:none; float:left;}
  h1{ margin:0px;}
  
  #home{ height:1000px; width:100%; background:gray; padding:10px;}
  #about{ height:1000px; width:100%; background:green; padding:10px;}
  #service{ height:1000px; width:100%; background:teal; padding:10px;}
  #contact{ height:1000px; width:100%; background:red; padding:10px;}
 </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
  <ul class="myNav nav">
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="home">
<h1>Home</h1>
</div>

<div id="about">
<h1>About</h1>
</div>

<div id="service">
<h1>Service</h1>
</div>

<div id="contact">
<h1>Contact</h1>
</div>
```

Actually i have to use `bookmark` with `top navigation fixed` that is not working properly together anybody can do it?

I know it's because of `position:fixed` of navigation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for pure css add `div h1 { margin-top:40px}` and below using jQuery

```js
$('.myNav a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var cid = '#' + this.href.split('#')[1];
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(cid).offset().top - 40
    }, 500);
})
```

```css
#home {margin-top:40px}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  
  .myNav {
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
  }
  
  .myNav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
  }
  
  h1 {
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  #home {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    background: gray;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  #about {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  #service {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    background: teal;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  #contact {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="myNav nav">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="home">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="about">
    <h1>About</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="service">
    <h1>Service</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="contact">
    <h1>Contact</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements with `fixed` position are taken outside of the layout flow, and don't reserve space for themselves. Since the `nav` was taken out of the flow, the 1st section home is moved up, and it's covered by the fixed nav.

A simple solution is to change the position to [sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning).

> A stickily positioned element is treated as relatively positioned
>   until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated
>   as fixed.

Note: `position: sticky` is not supported by IE.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.myNav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

.myNav li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0px;
}

#home {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

#about {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

#service {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: teal;
  padding: 10px;
}

#contact {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="myNav nav">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="home">
  <h1>Home</h1>
</div>

<div id="about">
  <h1>About</h1>
</div>

<div id="service">
  <h1>Service</h1>
</div>

<div id="contact">
  <h1>Contact</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly sticky isn't supported that well at all yet I guess - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/4hxrjmxk/1/

```css
*{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
  .myNav{ width:100%; background:#ccc; position:fixed; top:0px;}
  .myNav li{ list-style:none; float:left;}
  h1{ margin:40px 0px;}

  
  #home{ height:1000px; width:100%; background:gray; padding:10px;}
  #about{ height:1000px; width:100%; background:green; padding:10px;}
  #service{ height:1000px; width:100%; background:teal; padding:10px;}
  #contact{ height:1000px; width:100%; background:red; padding:10px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myNav nav">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="home">
  <h1>Home</h1>
</div>

<div id="about">
  <h1>About</h1>
</div>

<div id="service">
  <h1>Service</h1>
</div>

<div id="contact">
  <h1>Contact</h1>
</div>
```

Just changed the below code

```
h1{ margin:40px 0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 *{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
  .myNav{ width:100%; background:#ccc; position:fixed; top:0px;}
  .myNav li{ list-style:none; float:left;}
  h1{ margin:0px;}
  
  #home{ height:1000px; width:100%; background:gray; padding:10px;}
  #about{ height:1000px; width:100%; background:green; padding:10px;}
  #service{ height:1000px; width:100%; background:teal; padding:10px;}
  #contact{ height:1000px; width:100%; background:red; padding:10px;}
  
  .margin-top-40{
  margin-top:40px;
  }
  h1{padding-top:20px}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
  <ul class="myNav nav">
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="home" class="margin-top-40">
<h1>Home</h1>
</div>

<div id="about">
<h1>About</h1>
</div>

<div id="service">
<h1>Service</h1>
</div>

<div id="contact">
<h1>Contact</h1>
</div>
```

try this.